# Usuário não fica autenticado Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Não consigo fazer o usuário ficar autenticado, para ele entra na minha rota com o middleware auth... eu consigo logar mas não consigo ficar com o usuário logado, por exemplo não consigo entra em nenhuma rota com middleware auth e nen usar nenhuma método helper Auth::user()...

### Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

Route::get('/usuario',['uses' => 'UsuarioController@index','as' => 'index']);

});

Route::get('/login',['uses' => 'UsuarioController@login','as' => 'login']);
Route::post('/login',['uses'=>'UsuarioController@checkLogin','as' => 'VerificarLogin']);
```

### Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request; use Auth;

class UsuarioController extends Controller{

   public function login () {

       return view('Inicial.login');
   }
   public function index () {

       return view('usuario.index_Usuario');
   }

   public function checkLogin (Request $request){

        //$credentials = ['email'=>$request->get('email'),'password'=>$request->get('senha')];

        $email = $request->get('email');
        $password = $request->get('senha');

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {

            return redirect()->route('index');
        }else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

### Auth.php

```
    <?php

return [



    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'usuario',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'usuario' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'usuario',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'usuario' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Usuario::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],



    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

### App\Usuario

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Usuario extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = ['nome','email','password'];

  //  protected $fillable = ['Usuario_Nome','password','email','Usuario_DtNascimento','Usuario_Role']; //fillable para inserção em massa

    protected $table = "usuarios";
}
```

Comment: poste a classe  `App\Usuario::class` por favor

Comment: @VirgilioNovic estou no chat estouro de pilha man, qualquer aparece lá ^^

Comment: Eu acho que tem alguma coisa errada nas parte de configuração... mas, eu não sei dizer, porque mudou a classe de autenticação?

Comment: qual configuração ? tipo eu criei esse projeto do zero só para testar e ainda sim continua não pegando

Comment: se quiser mais informação só falar que vou postando, passei o dia hj tentando resolver isso ...

Comment: pasta `config\Auth.php` mas, eu não sei porque não tem como testar, mas, não precisa mudar a classe de autenticação que já vem pronta ...!!! direto vejo o pessoal mudando só para adicionar campos, porque, não adiciona na mesma entendeu.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73790/discussion-between-joan-marcos-and-virgilio-novic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu passei por um problema similar por algumas vezes e demorei para compreender o motivo.

O Laravel cria uma variável no navegador que define o token da sessão para ser transacionado durante a navegação.

Este dado é como um cookie, que é específico ao domínio e precisa bater com a sessão no servidor.

O problema é que se você não especificar a URL correta no .env a aplicação pode não funcionar.

Em alguns casos nunca enfrentei problema, mesmo mantendo localhost no APP_URL, porém, já em outros casos a página do Login apenas fica se atualizando sem exibir nada, nem mesmo mensagens Flash, pois elas também utilizam da sessão para funcionar.

Portanto, para entender se este é o problema:

1. Verifique se sua aplicação esta criando no browser o cookie / session storage ou local storage com um token;
2. Verifique se a cada novo acesso, há um novo arquivo de sessão na storage/sessions ou na tabela sessions (caso tenha específicado database para as sessões).
3. Testar as mensagens Flash que usam session;

Percebendo que o problema é este:

1. Especifique de forma correta no .env o domínio que você utiliza para trabalhar;
2. Verifique se há permissões de gravação no diretório storage/sessions;
3. Limpe caches do Laravel: php artisan cache:clear
4. Limpe os caches no navegador.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Man o problema está no banco de dados... por algum motivo quando eu troco de banco de dados ele consegue autenticar o usuário, tem alguma noção sobre isso ?

Comment: Quando você diz trocar banco de dados, seria apenas o banco mesmo ou trocar para outro tipo de banco? Tipo de Mysql para Mongo?
Se você tiver usando as sessões no banco de dados, confirme se o banco novo possui a tabela sessions (caso não tenha rodado as migrations).

Comment: Não de banco propriamente dito mas sim bancos mysql, qual troquei de banco pegou normal e quando volto para o outro banco não funfa, a diferença entre os dois banco é que um não tem nenhum relacionamento mas o outro tem alguns relacionamentos. O que posso relacionamento não funciona já o que não tem funciona normalmente

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas creio que a questão do relacionamento não tenha relação com a auth.
Confirme se esta setado como file o session no seu .env.
Caso seja database, confira se existe a tabela sessions no banco sem relacionamentos.

Comment: Está com file o session no .env. Quando troquei o nome do meu campo id, Tava assim "ID_Usuario" mudei para "id" funciona perfeitamente, agora o porque eu não tenho nenhuma ideia, sabe alguma coisa sobre isso ?

Comment: Se estiver usando o modelo padrão de auth do Laravel, ele usa o que é definido na migration dos usuários, onde a coluna se chama id.

Creio que para funcionar da outra forma, precisa especificar no Model do Usuario que o id do dado é ID_Usuario.

Comment: sim sim, conseguir corrigir, o padrão é id, tem um comando que você pode trocar o campo $primaryKey = "Nome do novo id". Vlw man ajudou tmj. Vota ae ^^

Comment: Fico feliz que tenha dado certo!
Eu sou novo aqui e não sei se isso é uma boa prática, mas acredito que seria útil para os próximos se você editasse sua pergunta pois ela não explicou realmente qual problema você estava enfrentando, assim ajuda os próximos que tiverem o mesmo problema.
Alias, ressalto que não sei se isso é uma boa pratica aqui na comunidade, estou apenas pensando no próximo.

Answer (score 0):

Passei por um problema assim usando o laravel 8, resolvi colocando no model `User` uma variavel protegida de nome `$primaryKey` com o valor de nome igual a chave primaria da tabela `User`.

Ex:

```php
protected $primaryKey = 'id_user';
```

Espero que ajude alguém!